# Pimcore 5 search/list Asset by metadata via API

Tags: php, pimcore, pimcore-v5

Is there a way to search Asset by metadata?
I want to list all assets having a specific metadata value via PHP Api or Rest API?
I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

About PHP API I think that there is only something like this:

```
$assets = new Asset\Listing();
$assets->onCreateQuery(function (\Pimcore\Db\ZendCompatibility\QueryBuilder $select){
    $select->join('assets_metadata', 'id = cid');
});
$assets->addConditionParam('name = ?', 'title');
$assets->addConditionParam('data = ?', 'mytitle');
foreach ($assets->getAssets() as $asset) {
    $output->writeln($asset->getFullPath());
}
```